# What serialization method is used for an ActiveMQ NMS C# object message?

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic, nms

I'm planning on using Apache NMS for ActiveMQ messaging, and am wondering what serialization method is going to be used on the objects I send?  XML/Binary?  What controls the serialization and how can I customize it?

Does anyone have experience doing this with C# objects?  Are there any pitfalls that you know of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default is System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter for IObjectMessage.

You can set your own by e.g.

```
IObjectMessage m = session.CreateObjectMessage();

((ActiveMQObjectMessage)m).Formatter=new SoapFormatter();//Or any IFormatter
```

You'd need to set the formatter before accessing IObjectMessage.Body on the receiver side if you're not sending objects with the default BinaryFormatter.

If you wish, you can also send/receive IByteMessage/ITextMessage and serialize your objects to the messages yourself in any way you'd like.

Comment: Any good info on the backward compatibility of the binary format? What happens with a removed/added field?

Comment: Seems in practice(in my limited experience atleat) missing fileds just get their default values. This serialization has nothing to do with NMS/ActiveMQ though. There's lots of questions regarding serialization on stackoverflow, poke around those.